# Send data from Woocommerce to Laravel via webhook

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, woocommerce, webhooks

I'm using Woocommerce webhooks to listen out for every time an order is created/updated/deleted.

I've setup the webhook in Woocommerce as follows

[image]

In my Laravel routes file I have set up the route as follows:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

// API routes...
Route::post('api/v1/orders/create', function (Request $request) {
    Log::debug($request->all());
    return $request->all();
});
```

However, when I view the logs as well as the return data in POSTMAN, all I get is an empty array.

Any HTTP method other than 'GET' throws a **MethodNotAllowedException**

I'm not sure of any other way in Laravel to consume data other than with Request $request.

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan dump-autoload`?

Comment: There is no other routes named `api/v1/orders/create` in your route file ? Also check to see if Woocommerce isn't adding a trailing `/` to the Delivery URL. View your Laravel Access Logs. If there is anything after `/create` then it'll be attempting GET instead of a POST.

Comment: @giollianosulit no. the route itself works fine. If I make a random log entry it works. It's just the $request->all() that returns an empty array.

Comment: Sorry, see my edited post and let me know if that helps

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd you mean composer dump-autoload?

Comment: @giollianosulit If I log $request->fullUrl() I get "http://vcc-backoffice.local/api/v1/orders/create" Is this correct?

Comment: If you are using lower then L5 use `php artisan dump-autoload`

Comment: It looks fine actually, have a look at the Woocommerce Logs. It seems that they log every request that fires. (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/webhooks/) - Make sure its actually a POST request. If it is, then try the above and do `php artisan dump-autoload` which will regenerate the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding of routing in Laravel, the input that you pass in to the function is meant to actually be variables for your route.

So if you had a route in your API:
`api/v1/orders/{id}/create` then in the route function you'd pass in id as the method argument. So this would be correct:

```
Route::post('api/v1/orders/{id}/create', function ($id) {
  Log::debug($id);
  return $id;
});
```

It's looking for request in your route definition.

Rather create a controller. Then in your `routes.php` use this:
`Route::post('api/v1/orders/create', 'OrdersController@create')`

That tells your routing to redirect all HTTP POST calls to `api/v1/orders/create` to the `OrdersController.php` and the `create()` method within that controller.

In your controller, you'll be able to use the `$request` variable as an input argument and it should work.

So in `OrdersController.php`:

```
class OrdersController extends Controller {

   public function create(Request $request) {
     Log::debug($request->all());
     return $request->all();
   }

}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: **edited** never mind. Yes having your function in a controller will work as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. My route in api.php is as follow.

```
 Route::post('/woocommerce/webhook/', 'Api\WoocommerceController@test');
```

And my controller action is as follow.

```
public function test()
{
    $payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
    $payload = json_decode( $payload, true);
    \Log::info(json_encode( $payload));
    return response()->json([ 'data' => $payload, 'status' => \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::HTTP_OK]);
}
```